# In Java, what does a reference to Class.class do?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a small Android application, but this is more of a Java question than an android question. Looking through the tutorials there are lines that look like:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

what exactly does the "MyService.class" field represent?  Is that just a reference to the class for a template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andy's answer is definitely correct, but I want to expand on the point a little.

`.class` is a special syntax for obtaining an instance of a Class object.  It can be used when only the type is available and no instance of the related object is around.  It can be used with any concrete type name, including arrays and primitives.  For instance, `int.class` is valid.

This way (and other ways) to get a Class object are documented in the old [Sun reflection API docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html).

The special `.class` syntax often appears in idiomatic usage as a "type token" in generic code.  A class literal obtained with `.class` is called a type token when "passed among methods to communicate both compile-time and runtime type information" ([Joshua Bloch's Effective Java 2e](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), p. 142).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `MyService.class` returns a Class object that represents the class MyService. The Intent uses it to identify which Service or Activity you're intending to start.

Comment: Is there more information on java's use of the .class deal? I understand what the result of using it is and such, but why does java use this implementation? Why does that syntax even exist instead of just calling like new MyService().

Comment: I'm no expert, but I suspect it has something to do with Android's architecture trying to minimize or hide the developer's interaction with explicit Activity or Service object creation. Don't know specifically why, but I'll try to find out.

Comment: It's usually done because of the type-erasure of Java generics.  You can pass .class to a method with the the parameter type Class<T> in order to capture the run-time type of a class, since you can't safely do much with a generic parameter itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `MyService.class` allows you to get the Class object describing the MyClass class, from the class name alone (as opposed to have an instance of the class to ask for `object.getClass()`).

Answer (score 1):

In JVM, when a class is loaded, an object of the type `Class` represents the loaded class in memory. `com.abc.MyClass.class` is a literal expression that represents the `Class` object for the class `com.abc.MyClass`.

The same `Class` object can also be obtained by calling `myClassReference.getClass()` method if you have a reference to an object of the class.

The `Class` object can be used to find the information on the structure of the class, access fields, invoke methods and instantiate objects of the class using Java Reflection API.