# Please confirm what .class does in java

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, what does a reference to Class.class do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295163/in-java-what-does-a-reference-to-class-class-do)

Firstly apologies for asking this question here. I know it's a simple question and can probably be answered quite quickly and easily. However searching for Java .class is such a loaded search term it brings up nothing useful.

Having said that, I just started learning Java and I just came across something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ReminderManageActivity.class);
```

I am not sure, but I think ReminderManageActivity.class is an attribute that gives a string of the name of the class? Is that correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it sounds stupid, but `class` is a `Class` object that represent the Class.

If you want to instantiate / use **some** class, and you want to get this class as parametr, you can't just write `Intent i = new Intent(this, ReminderManageActivity);` since `ReminderManageActivity` is not an object.

Comment: Reminds of good ole Russel's Paradox http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/

Comment: don't get me started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065998/how-to-declare-class-class-with-valid-generics

Answer (score 3):

In Java, given an object, an instance of a class, you can get the class name by coding the following:

```
Class clazz = obj.getClass();
String clazzName = clazz.getName();
```

Sometimes you want you want to create a Class object for a given class. In this case you can do so by writing code similar to the following example:

```
Class clazz = MyClass.class;
```

[source](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/05/08/javaclass/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just started learning java than you will see more about this when you will study Type Information or RTTI(Runtime Type Information)

```
ReminderManageActivity.class
```

is called a class literal and it produces a reference to the Class object, which contains information about the class in question.
It is similar to the static method :

```
Class.forName("ReminderManageActivity");
```

Comment: Hey,

I see from one of your questions you started Learning Java quite recently too. I just jumped in at Android without learning much Java. I figure at some point I am going to have to dive into that too. Just out of interest if you don't mind sharing... What resources/books are you using to teach yourself?

Comment: I read "Thinking in java" 4th Edition by Bruce Eckel. I just finished it and I can say that it is a very good book for somebody that is trying to learn java.

Comment: Ahh yes. I forgot about that one. I heard good things about it. I will be sure to pick it up. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

It is an instance of java.lang.Class which is part of Java Refleciton API. You can get more informaiton about the API [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because everything in Java is an object, so even classes can be represented by objects.

`ReminderManageActivity.class` returns a Class object representing the `ReminderManageActivity` class.

A Class object contains information of a class, such as class' name, class' method, class's variables etc. You can look at the class API for more information: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html